# Nazi Germany - Income of low-wage workers, and prices of food and other items?

Tags: nazi-germany

I'm trying to write a fictional piece in which the main character is an unemployed Jew, searching for jobs on the streets. Assume that he (the character) finds a temporary low wage job to do, like cleaning or helping out with things, not by actually getting employed.

1. How much would a small low-wage job in Nazi Germany have paid (in **German Marks**, the currency in the time of Nazi Germany)? This piece takes place in **1935**, after the hyperinflation of Germany. Prices should be relatively stable and regular.
2. What were the average prices of basic food staples, like bread/meat/milk and common items?

I need a sense of what and how many common items could a temporary low-wage German worker buy with their income.

Comment: If I remember correctly, Victor Klemperer speaks about these sorts of things in his diary. That would probably be a good place to start.

Comment: [This](http://www.daten.statistik.nuernberg.de/JB/1935/seiten/JB_1935_016.htm) might help. The top row is the official appartment rental statistics of Nuremberg in 1914 and 1933 for buildings constructed before 1918. The prices are per year.

Comment: The hyperinflation was in 1923.

Comment: Since it's set in 1935: Before or after the [Nuremberg Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuremberg_Laws)? You should really get your history right.

Comment: The currency before 1945 was the Reichsmark (RM). The Deutsche Mark (DM) came after the war.

Comment: @MartinSchröder After the Nuremberg Laws

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find a couple of figures concerning wages.  According to [HistoryLearningSite](http://www.historylearningsite.co.uk/nazi-germany/the-nazis-and-the-german-economy/):

> The KdF also involved itself in introducing a scheme whereby the
>   workers could get a car. The Volkswagen – People’s Car – was designed
>   so that most could afford it. The Beetle, designed by Ferdinand
>   Porsche, cost 990 marks. This was about 35 weeks wages for the average
>   worker. To pay for one, workers went on a hire purchase scheme. They
>   paid 5 marks a week into an account.
>
> Theoretically, when the account had reached 750 marks the worker would
>   be given an order number which would lead to them receiving a car. In
>   fact, no-one received a car. The millions of marks invested into the
>   scheme were re-directed into the rapidly expanding weapons factories.

Not a great business practice, but the quote gives us a number to work from. Doing the math this works out to an average wage of 28.28 Marks per week.

Another source, a book published in 2000, [Hitler:1889-1936 Hubris](https://books.google.com/books?id=TpVrCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT496&dq=german%20worker%20wage%20in%20MArks%201935%20crisis&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwih9pH3kanUAhUL94MKHT2wCSgQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=german%20worker%20wage%20in%20MArks%201935%20crisis&f=false), by Ian Kershaw has some figures within it showing nearly 50% of German workers earned

> 18 Reich Marks or less per week, which was substantially below the
>   poverty line.

So wages for *German* workers in this era could be expected to typically fall between 18 and 28 Marks per week.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't find any real figures on food prices however.  The searches kept getting stuck on the 1923 'wheelbarrows' full of Marks to buy a loaf of bread type quotes.

Comment: No worries, I'll try to find some. Thanks!

Comment: According to the Rise and Fall of the Third Reich, no cars were actually delivered to the workers who paid layaway and it was a big scam.

Comment: Noted, expanded the entry from same source, reflecting the final outcome of this 'investment'.  Still gives a numerical basis for computing wages to answer the original question.

Comment: @ClintEastwood Today I learned that the first KickStarter took place in Nazi Germany.

Comment: Wages and consumer prices (and rations) were fixed by the government, weren't they? No independent unions that went on strike nor any individual negotiations. No real price formation for consumers and wage earners.