# How many Reichsmarks would a piano lesson have cost in Germany during 1930 - 39?

Tags: nazi-germany

I have learnt in history that the Reichsmark became extremely inflated, but I think people still used it as currency, just in ridiculous amounts to buy otherwise "cheap" produce (such as bread) using a huge stack of cash. But if a piano lesson is, say, 60$ an hour, how many Reichsmarks would that have cost? Or was another currency used instead? Google doesn't really give any results and I expect its a pretty niche thing to ask.

I am writing a piece of historical fiction, that's why I'm looking for this information.

Comment: Hmmm so it is unfeasible. That's what I thought. But then what "currency" would people use for something like a piano lesson? I think because it something so unnecessary, and not a nessity, that its difficult to reason how one would even pay for them consistently on a weekly basis.

Comment: Also yeah, I made an account using my actual Stack Exchange account - I wonder if I can link this guest question to this account?

Comment: Double check hyperinflation vs these dates...

Comment: The [Reichsmark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reichsmark) was introduced in 1924, after the 1921-23 hyperinflation

Comment: @Henry oh huh that works then

Comment: You can see some info on typical wages I found for a similar question [here](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/38433/16951)

Comment: The currency before the introduction of the Reichs-/Rentenmark (RM) was simply called 'Mark' (M).

Comment: A *hyper* inflation is a rapidly moving target. It doesn't make sense to ask what the value of something would have been over the whole span of a hyperinflation. You would need to tie it down to a particular point in time. The price one week might be substantially larger than the previous week.

Comment: The Hyperinflation came effectively to an end on the 20th of November 1923 when the rate of the Rentenmark to (Paper-)Mark was set at 1:1 Billion. So that part of the question is moot, since the question asks about the timeframe 1930 to 1939.

Comment: @MarkJohnson You are not using the word "billion" in its currently accepted sense of a thousand million, but in a no longer commonly used sense of a million million.

Comment: @CMonsour Yes, the rate was 1:1 Trillion and a maximum of 3.2 Billion Rentenmark was allowed to issued. The German word **Milliarden** is translated to English as *billion* (just as **Billionen** is translated as *trillion*), so sometimes gets confused. [German Rentenmark - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_Rentenmark#History)

Comment: @MarkJohnson Yes, but if you are writing in English "billion" is the English meaning, and that has unambiguously been "a thousand million" since 1974, unless you italicize it as a foreign word.

Answer (score 2):

The [hyperinflation of 1923](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperinflation_in_the_Weimar_Republic) ended in November 1923 with the introduction of the Rentenmark and, in August 1924, of the Reichsmark. The value of German money became stable again and remained so until WWII.

[This article](https://www.diw.de/documents/publikationen/73/diw_01.c.401322.de/36-8.pdf) has average wages for various industries in 1935 on page 30. They are between 50 and 100 Pfennigs, i.e. betweeen 0.5 to 1 Mark. Piano lessons would probably considerably more expensive than the hourly wage of an industry worker, but probably not much more than a day's wage?

Comment: True, but the Rentenmark was a temporary expedient.  The Reichsmark followed in 1924 and remained reasonably stable until WWII.

Comment: The Reichsmark was just a different name for the same thing though, wasn't it?

Comment: No.  For one thing, the Reichsmark was legal tender. They traded at par, so they tended to represent the same value, but they were definitely not the same thing, just as the private currencies printed by corporations in the early 1920s were not Papiermark even though they were exchanged for them at par.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Is it better now?

Comment: The Rentenmark was issued against an amount of public property (up to 3.2 Billion Marks in Gold), therefore only a certain amount of notes/coins could be issued and (theoreticaly) redeemed in property. This was the effect that stopped the Hyperinflation. The Reichsmark was later issued as a 'normal' currency as we understand it today.

Comment: @CMonsour Notes issued by corporations (also towns, cities etc.) were not redeemed by the Reichsbank, but had to be redeemed by those that issued them.

Comment: @MarkJohnson I didn't claim the Reichsbank redeemed corporate scrip, just that people traded them at par (with each other).  The Federal Reserve doesn't redeem currencies of "dollarized" countries, either.

Comment: @MarkJohnson I realize the word "exchange" may have been ambiguous, but one can't edit comments ...

Answer (score 1):

The PDF in the source below lists, year for year, **the buying value** in Euros of 2020.

- 1930: 1 RM = € 3.70
- 1933: 1 RM = € 4.60
- 1936: 1 RM = € 4.40
- 1939: 1 RM = € 4.30

---

**Sources**:

- [Table of buying power (in Euro) between 1810 and 2020: Kaufkraftäquivalente historischer Beträge in deutschen Währungen - Source: Deutsche Bundesbank](https://www.bundesbank.de/resource/blob/615162/d55a20f8a4ecedd6d1b53e01b89f11c4/mL/kaufkraftaequivalente-historischer-betraege-in-deutschen-waehrungen-data.pdf) (PDF)
- [Historical values 1890-2014](https://www.was-war-wann.de/historische_werte/)

  - [Food: Lebensmittel Preise Preisentwicklung](https://www.was-war-wann.de/historische_werte/lebensmittelpreise.html)

    - [Bierpreisentwicklung - Bierpreis/Liter](https://www.was-war-wann.de/historische_werte/bierpreise.html)
  - [Wages: Monatslohn Entwicklung - Was verdiente ein Arbeiter](https://www.was-war-wann.de/historische_werte/monatslohn.html)